# How to build a data warehouse based on an entity attribute value database?

Tags: database, database-design, data-warehouse

Is it possible to create a data warehouse based on an [entity attribute value](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entity%E2%80%93attribute%E2%80%93value_model) database?

If so, how?

Basically I have data in the following format:

```
id  name   value
----------------
1   name1   10
1   name2   20
1   name3   30
2   name1   40
2   name2   50
2   name3   60
...
```

instead of the following:

```
id name1 name2 name3
--------------------
1   10    20    30
2   40    50    60
```

The problem I have is that there is no specific set of names/measures I can put in the fact table.

`name1`, `name2` and `name3` are **not known in advance** (not even how many of them could exist).

Any ideas on how to solve this? I searched on the Internet, but couldn't find any relevant information. Any help is greatly appreciated...

**Note**: I don't have any experience building data warehouses. I'm currently reading:
The Data Warehouse ETL Toolkit: Practical Techniques for Extracting, Cleaning, Conforming, and Delivering Data (by Ralph Kimball)

---

So to answer [Ben (from comments)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358709/how-to-build-a-data-warehouse-based-on-an-entity-attribute-value-database#comment16596850_12358709): "**Your table is actually normalised... why would you want to de-normalise it?**"

**Long answer**:
Our customer uses a tool which allows him to drag and drop dimensions & measures from an OLAP cube in a workspace and then shows him the selected data.

If I use [the model Paul Grimshaw suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12358802/354009) the customer would need to drag the name in the workspace and then add a filter for name to be equal for example with `name1` (if he so desires).

On the other hand if the customer would have a list of names he could drag in the workspace he would need only one action (ease of use) to access the data associated with `name1` (just an example). And there is one more reason: discoverability. The customer can look at the list of available names and just choose from it instead of adding a filter for name (and he would need to know the exact name).

**Short answer**: ease of use for customer (which includes discoverability of names).

Comment: I forgot to mention that name1, name2 and name3 are not known in advance (not even how many of them could exist).

Comment: @Ben Putting metadata into columns is not normalization. It's just [bad design](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/01/this-should-be-fun-to-watch.html).

Comment: @IgorPopov Does each distinct "name" have a distinct, different business meaning? So, for product ID 1, it has a "name" called "weight" with a measure 50, and a "name" called "length" with a measure 25?

Comment: @NWest: Exactly. Each "name" has a distinct business meaning.

Comment: @NWest, there as no indication that this was metadata when I wrote my comment; it just looks like a two column pk is needed and then everything is fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dealing with Entity-Attribute-Value structures is tricky when reporting off of relational models, never mind dimensional models.

We deal with this by building a "dynamic attribute" table of the "attribute" column - in this case, the "name" column".

Essentially, during the batch ETL process, we drop the old table, and create a new one. The DDL for the new one is generated by selecting the distinct values from (in your case) the "name" column, and then run as dynamic SQL on the database. Then, the ETL dynamically creates UPDATE or INSERT statements which load this table with each column from the EAV table, something like:

```
IF id doesn't exist in table, then:

INSERT INTO DYNAMIC_PIVOT_TABLE (id, $name) 
   SELECT id, value as "$name" where name = "$name";

ELSE 

UPDATE DYNAMIC_PIVOT_TABLE  ... etc
```

For each value of $name, we execute one insert or update to load that "subset" of EAV data into the appropriate column.

Now you've got a "fact" table with one dimension (ID) and measures for the rest of the items.

It gets even worse, however, if some of the things in "name" are not measures, but dimensional attributes. Then you have to do some crazy logic to determine what's a measure and what's an attribute.

Also, many OLAP tools need "static" metadata - dynamically changing metadata may cause problems for them.

Comment: Also - I would start with Ralph Kimball's earlier book "The Data Warehouse Toolkit", which goes over, in detail with good examples, how the dimensional model works.

Comment: Thank you for the reference and your answer... Unfortunately I have to deal with "dynamic" metadata (some key-value pairs coming from sailing ships where each ship has a different set of sensors). Because of the "dynamic" part we cannot compare ships side by side for a specific key (`name` in the initial post). There is rather an issue with the requirements, since there should be at least a set of keys (`name`) common for all the ships on which I could make some analysis.

Comment: @IgorPopov So they're asking for "side by side" analysis even when the data doesn't support it :-). You may want to just identify every possible dimension across all ships, then for the ships that don't have the appropriate sensors, those measures and attributes are just ignored for that row in the fact table. This way, you wouldn't have to build a dynamic fact at all (and I would expect that this structure wouldn't change often, as ships are large and adding a new ship might happen once a year or two?)

Comment: thanks again for suggestions :) I was thinking the same, but wanted some kind of external confirmation that I won't screw this up. All I need to do now is to check what the most common attributes are and use only those (as an initial step). If the customer needs other attributes he will just add other sensors on all the ships.

Comment: Note that I have evolved in my thinking and would not necessarily recommend a Kimball-style approach to anything. However, as you will hear that from the majority of data warehouse people, I'll leave the answer as is.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you can just use the "id" as a key to your fact table as well as a "Name id".

This would give you two dimensions (id and name), with a fact table with two keys (id and nameid), and one value field.

Comment: I'm not sure if the name dimension would make sense... at least I haven't found it documented anywhere... everywhere I look I find examples such as date & time dimensions or product dimension...

Comment: Umm, well, yeah, I guess I could use the name dimension.