# Data Warehouse: dimensional modeling for dynamic dimensions?

Tags: schema, data-warehouse, etl, datamart

We have a table called user_preferences. They are name value pairs and each user can custom define any number of preferences. What we want in our data warehouse/data mart is to provide reporting on these preferences as if they are dimensions. For example, a user preference can be gender, location, etc. And we want to find the number of actions performed by male users for a specific time frame.

How do people normally do this? Without exploding their data mart.

Answer (score 1):

This is what as known as the Entity-Attribute-Value data model, also known as the ["Everyone invents it, uses it once, then never uses it again"](http://tkyte.blogspot.com/2009/01/this-should-be-fun-to-watch.html) data model..

There are a myriad of reasons why it shouldn't be used, and a few edge cases where it should be used. However, assuming that you can't change your model to a better one, my [answer to this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12358709/how-to-build-a-data-warehouse-based-on-an-entity-attribute-value-database/12373599#12373599) should suffice for your case.